# Write multiple lists to a file with tabs between items and newlines between lists

Tags: python, list

Hi I'm trying to output multiple lists to a file with having each list in a separate line, and each element of the list separated by tab.

with lists being as:

```
['l1_el1', 'l1_el2', 'l1_el3']
['l2_el1', 'l2_el2', 'l2_el3']
```

The example of the output should be like:

```
l1_el1 l1_el2 l1_el3
l2_el1 l2_el2 l2_el3
```

Comment: This is what `str.join` was designed for: `" ".join(['l1_el1', 'l1_el2', 'l1_el3'])`

Comment: if you are using python3 you can even specify the separation in calls to the print function: `l = ['l1_el1', 'l1_el2', 'l1_el3'] ; print(*l, sep=" ", file=MY_FILE)`

Comment: Use [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) with the `excel_tab` dialect.

Comment: I have many lists, not just one. I want each of the lists in new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst1 = ['l1_el1', 'l1_el2', 'l1_el3']
lst2 = ['l1_el4', 'l1_el5', 'l1_el6']

with open('file.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for l in (lst1, lst2):
        fh.write('\t'.join(l) + '\n')
```

Comment: I have many lists, not just one. I want each of the lists in new line